# Fastest/One-liner way to collect duplicates in Ruby Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

What's the fastest/one-liner way to convert an array like this:

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 21]`

...into an array of objects like this:

`[{1 => 4}, {2 => 2}, {3 => 1}, {5 => 3}, {8 => 1}, {13 => 1}, {21 => 3}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve your desired format, you could append a call to map to your solution:

```
array.inject({}) { |h,v| h[v] ||= 0; h[v] += 1; h }.map {|k, v| {k => v}}
```

Although it still is a one-liner, it starts to get messy.

Comment: You can clean that up a bit by using a Hash with a default value: `array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }.map {|k, v| {k => v}}`

Comment: And to get it sorted (like in the question example), add `.sort_by { |o| o.keys[0] }` to it. *Now* it's messy. :)

Answer (score 5):

super basic, finally understand inject:

`array.inject({}) { |h,v| h[v] ||= 0; h[v] += 1; h }`

Not totally there, but almost

Comment: why do you ask if you know the answer?

Comment: It'scertainly not illegal to answer your own question. The SO FAQ even says it's okay, as long as it's in a question format.

Comment: to help other people find good information. it doesn't matter who answers it. don't worry, I don't have the desire to go around writing questions to things I have answers lined up for :).

Comment: There is a badge for that even called self-learner: Answered your own question with at least 3 up votes, so nothing illegal here.

Answer (score 5):

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
```

Not a huge difference but I prefer to be explicit with what I am doing. Saying `Hash.new(0)` replaces `{}` and `h[v] ||= 0`

Answer (score 4):

Requires 1.8.7

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 13, 21, 21, 21]
h = {}
a.group_by {|e| e}.each {|k,v| h[k] = v.length}
p h  # => {5=>3, 1=>4, 2=>2, 13=>1, 8=>1, 3=>1, 21=>3}
```