# rails sorting blog posts by title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I realize that this could be a rare occurrence (that two or more users would have the same blog post title) but this is something my client wants so, I have to figure it out.

I have a query @blog_posts (which is a query on Posts that changes based on location, etc). I need a way to to list out all the posts titles and how many times that title occurs within the query `@blog_posts`

Like this:

```
How to clean a car (2)
I love baseball (1)
```

Is there a standard practice for grouping and sorting?

**In summary, I need to count the occurrences in the query** `@blog_posts = Post.where(...)` **(for example) -- not all posts in existence.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you basically want to count occurrences: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502528/fastest-one-liner-way-to-collect-duplicates-in-ruby-array) could be adapted to your purposes.

If you're on 1.8.7 or newer, consider `group_by`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > posts = ["How to clean a car", "How to clean a car", "I love baseball"]
 => ["How to clean a car", "How to clean a car", "I love baseball"]
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > posts.group_by {|e| e}.map {|k, v| {k => v.length}}
 => [{"How to clean a car"=>2}, {"I love baseball"=>1}]
```

Comment: Thanks - I need to somehow access the title, count and post ID in the view.

Comment: I need to count occurrences in the query `@blog_posts = Post.where(...)` -- not all posts in existence.

Comment: Maybe something like `@blog_posts.group_by {|post| post.title}.map {|k, v| {k => v.length}}` then.

Comment: That works, any recommendation on how to get my view to show: `post.title (post.count)` - right now their printing all out like: Title2Title5Title8

Comment: Sorry, my original code was a little sloppy. Something like this would be more appropriate: `@blog_posts.group_by {|post| post.title}.each {|title, posts| puts "#{title} (#{posts.count})"}`

Comment: Thanks for your help -- my problem is I need for these to be links in my view ultimately I'm going to need this HTML: `<a href="?title=How%20to%20...>How to clean a car</a> (2)` -- I am able to do this as long as I have access to: _title, id, count in my view_. Any suggestions for view syntax? Thanks again.

Comment: I think it's basically the same, e.g.: `<% @blog_posts.group_by {|post| post.title}.each do |title, posts| %> <a ref="?<%= title %>><%= title %></a> <%= posts.count %> <% end %>` but my erb is a little rusty

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with a named scope inside your model (rails 3+ syntax):

```
scope :title_count, select('id, title, count(*) AS tcount').
    where('created_at >= ?', 10.days.ago).
    group('id, title').
    order('tcount desc')
```

In your controller:

```
@posts = Post.title_count
```

Comment: This is doing a query on all posts. I need it to perfom only on the posts selected in the query `@blog_posts = Post.where(...)` Not all posts in the entire database.

Comment: @masedesign - That's easy enough, just add a `where('...').` before the group line.  The scope is just chaining together all of these different query operations.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
@blog_post_counts = Post.find(
  :all, 
  :select => "COUNT(*) AS count, title", 
  :group  => "title", 
  :order  => "count DESC"
)
```

Of course you need to modify the query so that your conditions etc. are included.