# How to count occurrences of strings in objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to group, sort and count the occurrences of titles of a selection articles. I have selected my group of articles as follows:

`@articles = Article.find(:all, :where("distance < ?", specified_distance))`

Here out, I would like to group, sort and count the article titles that are **included** in `@articles` (not of **all** articles) for use in a view (as follows):

```
New York Yankees (3 Articles)
Boston Red Sox (1 Article)
Chicago Cubs (8 Articles)
```

This is not through usage of a many-to-many, it strictly string comparison, grouping, counting. I'm not sure how it is to be done. Is there a standard practice for doing this in Rails?

This is similar to what this user is asking for, but slightly different:

[rails sorting blog posts by title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914257/rails-sorting-blog-posts-by-title/6914418#6914418)

EDIT/

I must use `@articles` only (and not the physical query displayed above) because the query will often change and is much more complicated beyond that. So, my solution must refer to/from `@articles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model:

```
scope :articles_up_to, lambda { |distance| where("distance < ?", distance) }

scope :article_counts_up_to, lambda { |distance|
  articles_up_to(distance)
    .select("COUNT(*) AS count, title")
    .group("title")
    .order("count DESC")
}
```

In controller:

```
@article_counts = Article.article_counts_up_to(specified_distance)
```

Edit: 
This article on scopes may be helpful: http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html

Comment: I should have specified, that I must use `@articles` only  because the query will often change and is much more complicated beyond that.

Comment: I would express the complicated query as a scope and then chain this against that scope.

Comment: I edited my answer a couple of times. Still getting an error for the current version?

Comment: This is definitely all helpful, but I am editing someone else's code and I must use `@articles` (unfortunately). I won't be able to change everything all around to use scopes. But I understand that's not your problem. I'll have to figure something out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand you want to use `@articles`, so briefly, here's a (really messy) solution which doesn't involve changing the model, or building new SQL queries:

```
@article_counts = @articles
  .group_by(&:title)
  .map { |a| {:title => a[0], :count => a[1].size} }
  .sort { |a1,a2| a2[:count] <=> a1[:count] }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a group by method that you can use:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month